# What are some good widgets to add to a programming related blog (on blogger.com)?

Tags: blogs, widget

I decided to start my blog recently. Anyway I put it on blogger.com and was looking at the widgets you can add. There are some 100k+ of them.

By the way, I tried to add the StackOverflow search widget and it complained it was broken.

Anyway, I'm after some suggestions on good programming related widgets worth adding.

Answer (score 2):

[Syntax Highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/) -- Support for pretty much every language you might wish to post snippets of.

Answer (score 0):

A widget that allows access to documentation for countless APIs.

http://www.gotapi.com/widgets/index.html